# C++Builder send array using TCP

Tags: c++, tcp, c++builder

In C++Builder, I have to send a multi-dimensional array of `int` like:

```
int example[3][3];
```

using a TCP protocol.

I created a socket using this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UjrITeDk718

But I do not understand how to send just a multi-dimensional array instead of a string... Any hint?

CLIENT CODE:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
  IdTCPClient1->Connect();
  //send byte
  IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(Edit1->Text.Length());
  //send text
  IdTCPClient1->Write(Edit1->Text);


  //send request
  TStringList *SL = new TStringList;
  SL->Add(Edit1->Text);
  IdTCPClient1 ->WriteStrings(SL);
  delete SL;
  ListBox1->Items->Add(Edit1->Text+">>sent");


  int bytes = IdTCPClient1 -> ReadInteger();
  AnsiString resp = IdTCPClient1->ReadString(bytes);
  ListBox1->Items->Add(resp);
  IdTCPClient1->Disconnect();

}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

SERVER CODE:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
  : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
  int bytes =  AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();

  AnsiString request = AThread->Connection->ReadString(bytes);
  ListBox1->Items->Add(request);

  Edit1->Text=FormatDateTime("hh:mm AM/PM", Now());
  AnsiString risp = Edit1->Text;

  AThread->Connection->WriteInteger(risp.Length());
  TStringList *SL = new TStringList;
  SL->Add(risp);
  AThread->Connection->WriteStrings(SL);
  delete SL;
  ListBox1->Items->Add(risp+">> inviato");
  AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You haven't shown all your code. What's `IdTCPClient1`? See [mcve] and consider creating one to improve your question.

Comment: It is just a component of C++ Builder, IdTCPClient1 is the standard name if you select the TCP Client from Indy Clients... :)

Comment: Understood, but omitting this makes it difficult or impossible for people who don't have C++ Builder and don't have lots of extra time to watch a YouTube video (such as myself) to help diagnose your question.

Comment: @BlueFab FYI, your code is using Indy 9, which is outdated by over a decade.  Consider upgrading to Indy 10 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of how many dimensions your array uses, it still has a fixed byte size (`sizeof(int) * 3 * 3 = 36`), so you can use the `TIdTCPConnection::WriteBuffer()` and `TIdTCPConnection::ReadBuffer()` methods to send/receive it, eg:

```
IdTCPClient1->WriteBuffer(&example, sizeof(example));
```

```
AThread->Connection->ReadBuffer(&example, sizeof(example));
```

But, if you don't want to rely on that, then you could send/receive the `int` values individually using the `TIdTCPConnection::WriteInteger()` and `TIdTCPConnection::ReadInteger()` methods instead, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(example[i][j]);
}
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        example[i][j] = AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();
}
```

If you use a dynamically allocated array instead, you could then send the individual dimensions before sending the actual integers, that way the receiver would know how many integers to expect so it could allocate a suitable array to receive them, eg:

```
IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(3);
IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(3);

for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
        IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(example[i][j]);
}
```

```
rows = AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();
cols = AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();

example = new int*[rows];
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    example[i] = new int[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        example[i][j] = AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();
}
```

That being said, there are several problems with the code you have showed.

- Your client and server do not match each other:

  - Your client is sending a length-prefixed AnsiString, followed by a (not count-prefixed) TStringList.  It is then reading a length-prefixed AnsiString.
  - Your server is reading the client's length-prefixed AnsiString correctly, but is ignoring the client's TStringList.  It is then sending the length of an AnsiString but not sending the AnsiString itself, followed by a (not count-prefixed) TStringList.  The client will not read the TStringList correctly.
- Your TIdTCPServer::OnExecute handler is not synchronizing with the main UI thread when accessing the UI controls.  TIdTCPServer is a multi-threaded component, its events are fired in the context of worker threads, not the main UI thread.  You MUST synchronize when accessing the UI from a worker thread, or else bad things happen.

Try this instead:

Client:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    String s = Edit1->Text;

    int example[3][3];
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
           example[i][j] = (i*3)+j;
    }

    IdTCPClient1->Connect();
    try
    {
        //send byte length
        IdTCPClient1->WriteInteger(s.Length());
        //send text
        IdTCPClient1->Write(s);

        // send array
        IdTCPClient1->WriteBuffer(&example, sizeof(example));

        ListBox1->Items->Add(s + ">>sent");

        int bytes = IdTCPClient1->ReadInteger();
        String resp = IdTCPClient1->ReadString(bytes);
        ListBox1->Items->Add(resp);
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPClient1->Disconnect();
    }
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Server:

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
#include <IdSync.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TAddToListBoxSync : public TIdSync
{
public:
    String str;
    __fastcall TAddToListBoxSync(const String &s) : TIdSync(), str(s) {}
    virtual void __fastcall DoSynchronize() { Form1->ListBox1->Items->Add(str); }
};

class TSetEditTextSync : public TIdSync
{
public:
    String str;
    __fastcall TSetEditTextSync(const String &s) : TIdSync(), str(s) {}
    virtual void __fastcall DoSynchronize() { Form1->Edit1->Text = str; }
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdPeerThread *AThread)
{
    int bytes = AThread->Connection->ReadInteger();
    String request = AThread->Connection->ReadString(bytes);

    int example[3][3];
    AThread->Connection->ReadBuffer(&example, sizeof(example));

    TAddToListBoxSync *lb_sync = new TAddToListBoxSync(request);
    try {
        lb_sync->Synchronize();
    }
    __finally {
        delete lb_sync;
    }

    String risp = FormatDateTime("hh:mm AM/PM", Now());

    TSetEditTextSync *edt_sync = new TSetEditTextSync(risp);
    try {
        edt_sync->Synchronize();
    }
    __finally {
        delete edt_sync;
    }

    AThread->Connection->WriteInteger(risp.Length());
    AThread->Connection->Write(risp);

    lb_sync = new TAddToListBoxSync(risp + ">> inviato");
    try {
        lb_sync->Synchronize();
    }
    __finally {
        delete lb_sync;
    }

    AThread->Connection->Disconnect();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```